# manipulating elements of a numpy array in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have:

```
in = array([4, 3, 2, 1,
   -3, -2, -1,  0])
```

How do I subtract the previous element from the next element like this:

```
out = array([(3-4), (2-3), (1-2),
             (-3-1), (-2-(-3)), (-1-(-2)), (0-1)]
out = array([-1,-1,-1,-4,1,1,-1])
```

Comment: `out[1:]-out[:-1]`.  `diff` does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `np.diff()`:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([4, 3, 2, 1, -3, -2, -1, 0])
print(np.diff(arr)) # [-1 -1 -1 -4  1  1  1]
```

`np.diff()` returns an numpy array you just described: the differences between two adjacent elements.